# I want to create a button on my webpage that activates the action of a tab on the same page using jquery if possible

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, button, scrollto

I currently have a tab on my page (created with Jquery UI) that when clicked expands some content that is collapsed on page load.  I want to be able to activate that tab's action by pressing a separate button on the site.  For example, here is the jquery script that makes the tab work it uses Jquery UI core, and the scrollTo plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        collapsible: true,
        selected: -1
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".scrolltoanchor").click(function(){
        $.scrollTo($($(this).attr("href")), {
            duration: 750
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

And the tab looks like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li ><a href="#testimonial" class="scrolltoanchor">Testimonials</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="testimonial">
        <p>THE CONTENT IS HERE</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I want to put a button elsewhere on the page that expands this content and scrolls to the content, essentially this button, when clicked, will do the exact thing that the "Testimonials" `<li>` tab does.  It would expand #testimonial, and scrolls to it.

Comment: Have you tried triggering a click event on that anchor?

Comment: like <button type="button" onclick="location.href="#testimonials">Testimonials</button>  ?  would that work?

Comment: See this http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-tabs-toggle-with-radio-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you use the [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function on the element?

For example, if you had an element with the ID of 'button', the following code should do what you want:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('.scrolltoanchor').trigger('click');
});
​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YG4HC/)**.